# Linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following set linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n?$

$$X := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\mid α \cdot x = 0\}$$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$  is fixed.

I know that if we let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then  $\alpha \cdot x= q$  and $\alpha \cdot y=0$ too and this is closed under multiplication.

I am unsure if this is closed under addition. I think yes since $ax+ay=0$ $a(x+y)=0. $
I am just starting to deal with subspaces so I am not confident enough.

Comment: yep, the logic is good. This is a typical definition for a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Alternative proofs: It's the set of solutions of a homogeneous equation. It's the null space of the matrix $\alpha^T$. It's the orthogonal complement of the line spanned by $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly as you said it is a subspace.

The definition of subspace is:
Let K be a field (such as the real numbers), V be a vector space over K, and let W be a subset of V. Then W is a subspace if:

**1.** The zero vector, 0, is in W.

**2.** If u and v are elements of W, then the sum u + v is an element of W.

**3.** If u is an element of W and c is a scalar from K, then the scalar product cu is an element of W.

Lets prove:

**1.** zero vector is included, $\alpha · 0 = 0$. (This is not neccesary, it is redundant)

**2.** $\alpha ·(u+v)=\alpha ·u +\alpha ·v= 0$.

**3.** $c(\alpha·u)=c*0=0$.

Note.- This space is called the orthogonal complement of the linear subset generated by $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you! This was really useful. Would the same logic hold if α·x = b where  b ∈ R with b is non-zero ?

Comment: Not at all! Think a bit.
**2.** $\alpha ·(u+v)=\alpha · u+\alpha · v= b+b= 2b\neq b$. 
**3.** $c*(\alpha·u)=c*b\neq b$

Comment: Thanks! Your way of doing it makes it much simpler to understand than following the book

Answer (score 0):

Remember that to check if a set $S$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, you must check two things:

1) for all $x, y \in S$, we have $x + y \in S$.

2) for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $x \in S$, we have $cx \in S$.

It looks like you have ideas for proving these two things, you just need to formulate them better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. First we shall check that $X \neq \emptyset$, we see that $\mathbf{0} \cdot \alpha=0$, so $\mathbf{0} \in X$. Now, let $x_1,x_2 \in X$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. By definition you know that t $x_1\cdot \alpha=0=x_2 \cdot \alpha$, so $$\alpha\cdot (x_1+cx_2)=(\alpha \cdot x_1+c(\alpha \cdot x_2))=0+c\cdot 0=0,$$ so $x_1+cx_2 \in X$. This proves that $X$ is s subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.